Loose coupling for utility/helper classes
What solutions do you use to avoid tight coupling between classes when using utility classes like waithelpers, data formatting, selenium utils etc? I am using these classes having static methods, which is not ideal in terms of coupling

The concept of utility class/functions (UFC) is a dangerous one, because they tend to end up breaking the Single Responsibility Principle, as they will have clients with completely different reasons for changing the utility class/function.
But we can decrease the risk by decoupling the UFCs from its classes.
There are a few strategies:
1 - Dependency Injection
This way, you can easily change implementations of the UFCs:
public class ExampleClass {
    private final WaitHelper waitHelper;

    public ExampleClass(WaitHelper waitHelper) {
        this.waitHelper = waitHelper;
    }

    public void performAction() {
        waitHelper.waitForElement();
    }
}

interface WaitHelper {
    void waitForElement();
}

public class DefaultWaitHelper implements WaitHelper {
    public void waitForElement() {
        // Implementation
    }
}

2 - Factory Methods
If the constructions of the utilities is complex, Factory Methods can help to isolate this complexity:
public class WaitHelperFactory {
    public static WaitHelper createDefault() {
        // Some complex code here
        return new DefaultWaitHelper();
    }

    public static WaitHelper createWithCustomTimeout(TimeUnit unit, int value) {
        // Some complex code here
        return new DefaultWaitHelper(unit, value);
    }
}

Then in the clients:
WaitHelper waitHelper = WaitHelperFactory.createDefault();

WaitHelper waitHelper = WaitHelperFactory.createWithCustomTimeout(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 1);

3 - Mixins
Interfaces with default behavior can help to share functions between classes without creating static dependencies between them.
public interface WaitHelper {
    default void waitForElement() {
        // Implementation
    }
}

public class ExampleClass implements WaitHelper {
    public void performAction() {
        waitForElement(); // Method from the Interface, shared between all WaitHelper derivatives
    }
}

4 - Context objects
If several UFCs come together, you can inject them as a context object:
@Getter
public class TestContext {
    WaitHelper waitHelper;
    SeleniumUtils seleniumUtils;
}

public class ExampleClass {
    private final TestContext context;

    public ExampleClass(TestContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void performAction() {
        context.getWaitHelper().waitForElement();
    }
}

5 - Aspect-Oriented Programming (AOP)
Cross-cutting concerns, e.g. logging, can be implemented without creating dependencies using AOP.
E.g.
Let's say you have this page object class
public class LoginPage {
    private WebDriver driver;

    // Locators
    private By usernameField = By.id("username");
    private By passwordField = By.id("password");
    private By loginButton = By.id("loginButton");

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void enterUsername(String username) {
        driver.findElement(usernameField).sendKeys(username);
    }

    public void enterPassword(String password) {
        driver.findElement(passwordField).sendKeys(password);
    }

    public void clickLogin() {
        driver.findElement(loginButton).click();
    }
}

You can log the entries and exit results of the usages of the methods with an Aspect like this:
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class);

    // Pointcut to target methods in the LoginPage class
    @Pointcut("execution(* com.example.pages.LoginPage.*(..))")
    public void loginPageMethods() {}

    // Log method entry
    @Before("loginPageMethods()")
    public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        logger.info("Entering method: {} with arguments: {}",
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
                joinPoint.getArgs());
    }

    // Log successful method execution
    @AfterReturning(pointcut = "loginPageMethods()", returning = "result")
    public void logAfterReturning(JoinPoint joinPoint, Object result) {
        logger.info("Method executed successfully: {} with result: {}",
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
                result);
    }

    // Log exceptions thrown by methods
    @AfterThrowing(pointcut = "loginPageMethods()", throwing = "error")
    public void logAfterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable error) {
        logger.error("Exception in method: {} with message: {}",
                joinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
                error.getMessage());
    }
}


Thanks for the answer. What if the total no of “raw” java calls for these methods within the utility classes needs to be decreased? Can you think of any possible solution?

Can you detail what you mean by “raw” java calls within the utility classes?
Just guessing, but do you want to decrease the amount of code in the client classes that talk about the UFCs?
If so, the AOP approach removes completely the dependency - the AOP library takes care of calling the different pieces of code accordingly.
If AOP is a bazuca to k*ll an ant, the context objects approach will help to share a multitude of behaviors (logging, Selenium etc) in a single object that is injected in the clients; minimising the coupling.

The drawback of context objects is that they can become very complex. Managing them is important.
